# format multiline code to a single line

Tags: r, regex

I'm not quite sure of the terminology here. I'm doing a code parsing project to visualize the relationships between objects of an R script. Almost everyting works except for parsing and evaluating functions and loops. I don't think I have a good enough handle on regex to find the beginning/end of nested curly braces.

In the script, it might look like this:

```
something_above <- "above"

my_function <- function(x){
    x2 <- x^2 
    if(x2 >= 200){
        res <- "200+"
    } else {
        res <- "<200"
    }
    return(res)
}

something_below <- "below"
```

When I read it in, it looks like this

```
string <- '\r\nsometing_above <- \"above\"\r\n\r\nmy_function <- function(x){\r\n x2 <- x^2\r\n if(x2 >= 200){\r\n res <- \"200+\"\r\n } else {\r\n res <- \"<200\"\r\n}\r\n return(res)\r\n }\r\nsomething_below <- \"below\"\r\n'
```

I would like to be able to collapse the function into a single line like this

`... <- function(x){x2 <- x^2 ; if(x2 >= 200){res <- "200+" ; ...}; return(res)}\r\n ...`

so that each step within the function is separated by a `;` instead of a new line. I would, however, like to keep the new line `\r\n` pattern at the beginning of the assignment`\r\nmy_function` and once the function assignment is over `};return(res)}\r\n`.

The final result would be three lines:

```
[1] something_above <- "above"
[2] my_function <- function(x){x2 <- x^2; if(x2 >= 200 ...}
[3] something_below  <- "below"
```

Thank you.

Comment: why does your string start with `r` ?

Comment: Ah, poor copying. It's in the middle of a bunch of other stuff. should be `\r\n`, I edited the code.

Comment: I think what you want is to put everything in one line, adding `;` at the right places, except at the first level of the parse tree. So first you'll have to split by `\r\n` with `lines <- strsplit(string,'\r\n')[[1]]`. Then deparse the code with `dep <- deparse(lines)`. Then use sapply with a styling function. I don't know how to finish the job but package `styler` has a function `style_text` that might help. Though its use seems a bit esoteric to me.